# Using pandas, how do I loop through a dataframe row by row but with each row being its own dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am aware of:

```
for index, row in dataframe.iterrows():
```

But I wish for each row to be its own dataframe instead of the type series. How would I go about doing this? Do I have to convert it or this a better way of looping through?

Comment: The best is to not loop (if possible). If you provide a [mcve] with sample data, a clear statement of your problem, and the expected output you will get good advice on how to best solve your problem.

Comment: You never loop. Use vectorization instead.

Comment: @ALollz How could my problem description be clearer? And how would additional code help? I have a dataframe and I wish to access it row by row with each row being its own dataframe. Am I supposed to write the code for reading in my csv file to a dataframe? Surely that is unrelated to the problem and the example code I did put there would give people the idea of what I was looking for?

Comment: @OultimoCoder you could explicitly say which one is your goal here. From what we read it looks like you are aiming for a slow and not scalable solution.

Comment: Your statement is clear, but this is likely an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). We can help you loop through the DataFrame, though this is typically something you avoid in `pandas`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/55557758/4333359. What would be more useful is to explain the problem you need to solve (the one that "requires" iterrows), and then you'd get an answer to that, instead of a way to do something you should be avoiding in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

If you need each row as `DataFrame`

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    df.iloc[[i],:]

for index in df.index : 
    df.loc[[index],:]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest loading the dataframes into a list of dataframes, then you can access them individually.

```
df_list = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    df_list.append(df[index:index+1])
```

then you can access the list `df_list[0]` for example

Answer (score 0):

You can use [numpy.split](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.split.html)

```
dfs=np.split(df,list(range(1,len(df))),axis=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the usage.
From what I could guess (a function that only applies on a DataFrame), you have two options :

### Option 1

convert your row to a frame :

```
df_row = row.to_frame()
```

### Option 2

group your df (doing something as silly as resetting its index to have uniquely dataFrames of only 1 row), and apply the function to it :

```
df.reset_index().groupby('index_0').apply(func)
```